# Scrolling credits

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes, add-on

I used blender as all in one application. I model, animate and compose in it. Now I need to add a simple scrolling credits at the end on an animation.

**I want to know if there is a easy way to make scrolling credits only with blender.** The only way I can think is create a scene with the a text object and animate it vertically so it appear to be scrolling. But the text can be very long.

I'm also open to any addon for Blender that can archive this.

Comment: Do you have any design template / style guide you'd like to use for the Credits?

Comment: A slightly easier option would be to make an image of the entire text of the credits in gimp (or a similar program), add it in the compositor, and animate the y-offset.

Comment: @zeffii Not really. Only that they must be end scrolling credits, I mean text appearing from the bottom and disappearing through the top.

Comment: @Ezra nice point.

Comment: I recommend you design your credits in a program like inkscape or gimp (or whatever proprietary programs you prefer) and show an example...then people have something to work towards in potential answers.. If you're going to do credits you might as well make sure they are of the same high standard as the thing they're crediting.

Comment: @zeffii it's more a personal work so they don't need to be high quality. I will do some example to clarify the question as suggested.

Comment: Let me just get this out there, a proper video editing program will make this a *lot* easier. Text is editable in a window, and scroll speed is animatable. If you have that option, then do that instead. The below answers are more workarounds to use just Blender

Comment: People don't realize this, but with a little bit of effort Sverchok becomes every bit as intuitive as any other node tree. This script took me perhaps 5 minutes to write, 20 seconds to connect.. PyNodes add-ons are great for this kind of stuff (all of them, Sverchok, Animation Nodes, MotionTool too )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all, avoid using Blender's default font because it's the lazy option.

#### Option 1

The quick and dirty solution is to use TextEditor's own *Text To 3D Object* feature.
*TextEditor -> Edit -> Text to 3D Object*

That will give you two options:

- One Object
- One Object Per line.

My issue with this is it rather limits the amount of design aesthetic you can give to the Text.

#### Option 2

Naturally there's many many other options that would work, and this happens to show how to use [Sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) to generate credits. Warning, this may be overkill, but may interest to some. Especially scripters should read the code in `fast_credits.py` to see how Scripted Node works and how relatively easy it is to customize this script to do more advanced stuff.

I'm using a font called Cabin which comes in several weights including *Bold* and *Regular* and I've loaded those in using the node's properties on the node view rightside panel (press N to view it, with the Typography node selected/active).

[image]

> If you want multiple font weights for different text elements you simply add a Typography Node and load a font type into it.

Let's take some formatted bit of text, the words to the left of the Pipe symbol `|` will be *bold*, and to the right *regular*. And for the sake of this example i've set their align to be 'LEFT' and 'RIGHT' for either side of the pipe.

Titles:

```
Lead 1 | Jane Dough
Lead 2 | John Dough
Lead 3 | Ms Smith
Lead 3 | Mr White

Support 1 | Mr Pinker
Support 2 | Mr Red

Director | Mr Golder
```

The sverchok Typography node is a beast with almost all the features that the regular TextObject exposes via the Properties panel. The node is merely a notification of all that functionality (or what makes sense to me). You can see more options by pressing the "Show options" button on the node, this is incidentally where you can set the align orientation of all text that that node produces.

[image]

[image]

**some tips for this node tree**:

- If you make changes to the Titles text file its content is reread automatically upon any update in the node tree

  - using sliders
  - after pressing the Reload button on the Scripted Node.
    This means yes there is some redundant computation if the text stays the same, but if your Titles text is dynamically generated as a function of the frame number, then you get that handled for free.

[image]

Then add an Orthographic Camera and animate its position, render the output, and use the Sequence Editor to add the Credits to your already rendered animation.

**Some things to consider:**
Unless you are using specific features from Cycles you can use Blender Internal if it renders faster on your machine. A Cycles render of text is fast if you use an emission shader in your text objects and switch on AO to get fast lighting, maybe even render with transparent background.

Comment: [blendfile](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/285/)
My version of Zeffii's titles, ))

Answer (score 8):

As of Blender 2.76 [the VSE (sequencer) has a new Text Effect strip](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/Sequencer), which is worth considering too, but it is currently a basic implementation. It has been developed in the [Gooseberry Branch](https://gooseberry.blender.org/gooseberry-in-blender-master/) for the named alike Open Movie Project finally released as [Cosmos Laundromat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-rmzh0PI3c).

*Add -> Effect Strip -> Text*

[image]

As of October 2015:

downsides:

- <s>no font type change</s> Implemented in [2.8 beta](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/01/15/blender-developers-meeting-notes-14-january-2019/).
- multiple lines (text that contains new-line characters), is accessible via script only

  ```
  se = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor
  se.active_strip.text = 'foo\nbar'
  ```
- <s>no color settings</s> Implemented in 2.79, also the shadow color.

upsides:

- It has auto text reflow (configured by a wrap width), and dropshadow (on/off)

Comment: Feel free to update this answer when facts are no longer valid. I can only assume that the Text Effect strip will get a lot of improvements down the road.

Comment: I hope so. Not being able to change the font is pretty limiting.

Comment: Finally possible! :-)

Answer (score 6):

One way this can be done, is to create an image of your credits in Photoshop, GIMP, Inkscape, etc. This can then be animated in Blender to scroll.

I started this off by making a decently large image in GIMP, making sure to keep the vertical resolution bigger than the horizontal. At that point, I added in my text, using guides to keep things aligned better. Before exporting, I made sure to remove the default white background so that the background was transparent.

The first thing that should be done before importing the image, is making sure the renderer is set to Blender Internal, and enabling GLSL shading, which allows for all rendering to be done in the view port.

After that, I brought in the image using the import images as planes addon and made some adjustments to to the texture and materials settings to make the background transparent. I then key framed it to scroll.

All that was required after that was giving it a nice background, and rendering it out with the OpenGL render buttons.

[image]

While this may not be as flexible in Blender as @zeffii's method, it can be easier and more flexible to modify the image inside GIMP, rather than Blender, because there are more 2D effects that are available inside of GIMP.

When 3D text is necessary, @zeffii's method is definitely better.

Comment: Yeah, you can simply export SVG from inkscape / illustator and import those as 2d Curve paths. This is especially great if you are more comfortable in other packages. and have specific kerning requirements