# Importing image with original asspect ratio without cropping

Tags: video-sequence-editor

At the end of a video (resolution 1080x720) I wanted to display the 'credits'. I thought the most simple way way was making an image file (with GIMP) with all the text that I could import to blender and move (scroll) via keyframes. The file is of size 1080x5000px. This was getting cropped when transforming (after checking the 'image offset' box), which is what I want to avoid.

Here in detail what I did so far:

When I import it, it is automatically stretched to the size of the video:

[image]

For getting the original aspect ratio I read that I should check the option 'image offset, which looked promising:

[image]

But when I tried to make the image smaller and move it (via *effect strip>transform*) the rest of the 'credits' image was cropped/not visible anymore.

[image]

As you can see, this only shows the last line of the credits, the rest is cropped away and I have no idea why.
So can anyone tell me how to make the rest of the image visible again? Is there maybe another way of importing it?

Comment: try this addon, https://github.com/kgeogeo/VSE_Transform_Tools

Comment: It is said pretty much everything about credits in [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32585/scrolling-credits). The solution you're trying to make is the one proposed in comments there and it assumes you should animate the Y offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found right option, the only thing left is to animate it.

With your credits imported, find the best **Offset** options (both X and Y) to make them begin the credits being in the bottom and end - in the top of frame, and animate your found values:

[image]

So, in the 1st frame this value is -1850 for me, and in the last - around 230.

The result will be scrolling your text:

[image]

*text from [here](http://www.lincolninst.edu/subcenters/making-sense-of-place/cleveland/about/credits.asp)*

The much more in-depth solution is provided in [this solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32585/scrolling-credits)

Comment: Thank you for answering, my main problem was that only a part of the image was visible when I made it smaller, does that go away with the animation? (perhaps I shouldn't have written my question at the last line of my post=)

Comment: The problem is not clear then. You show in your question stretched image of credits, what will be on the first step of doing animation if rendered right from beginning. Why you want to make it smaller then ? What is your desired result ?

Comment: I resize the image because I need to adjust the size of the image such that it fills the whole screen. This is not the problem. The problem is depicted in the last image: The image is scaled by about factor 0.58 but on the screen you can only see a *part* of the whole image, there should be more of the image above but you can only see the very last line. Is it clear now what I mean? The original credits image is way taller, but you can only see that square that shows the very last part of it.

Comment: Why are you trying that image to fit the screen ? I understood your question like that: your credits image has 5000 pixels height and you'd like to make it scrolling. In that case you shouldn't *adjust* it within *one* frame, rather than *scroll* it during *all* the frames. And why did you lowered the resolution of the screenshots ?

Comment: I wanted to say it should fill the with of the screen. Yes the image has a height of about 5000px and I want to make it scroll, and I think I will be able to do that, but the problem is still, can you tell me why I can only see a small *part* of the image in the last screenshot? The credits-image is way taller than what we see on this screenshot. (I just linked to the smaller versions of the upper two because I wanted to emphasize that the problem is depicted in the last one. You can remove the `m` at the end of the file names to see the big screenshots again.)

Comment: It's shown like that because you changed something (along with scale) - that's what I can tell now. Upload your file, I'll try to find what's up there (just don't forget to pack images into it).

Comment: Oh that was actually the case! I just started from scratch and now it works! Thank you very much!