# Can you change the font in the Sequencer new Text Effect?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I find the default boring and wonder how to change it.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32585/scrolling-credits

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible to change the font on the Text effect as of 2.76. [Here's a workaround](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36422/8262)

Comment: Just had a spelunk into the source and found that the code for generating the VSE Text effect and the Stamp are the same and all the references to the font are hard coded. The developer even marked the lines with // XXX which appears to be a flag for janky code. Look for "do_text_effect" in "source/blender/blenkernel/intern/seqeffects.c" Maybe it will be fixed in 2.8

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the new 2.8 beta now you [can](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/01/15/blender-developers-meeting-notes-14-january-2019/). There now is a font selection box in the Text Effect Strip properties panel.

[image: Example of font selection]

Comment: can you point me to a tutorial that explains how to do this? I don't see anything about adjusting the font in the VSE...is there an Add-On I'm missing? I searched the Blender Manual and I Googled it and I even searched for add-ons but I'm not seeing anything. Any assistance would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It was explained in [Blender Today](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/01/17/custom-fonts-in-vse-blendertoday-live/).