# Can I apply "styles" to text strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've got a number of text strips through a video I'm editing - most of which ha the same colour and font. Currently I'm changing these on each strip manually by doing [Can you change the font in the Sequencer new Text Effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41767/can-you-change-the-font-in-the-sequencer-new-text-effect) - is there any way to, for example, set a style to each of the text effects, then change that style rather then having to manually go through each text strip? Or if not, at some way to change the default/all strips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select all of the text strips and then change ex. the color value of the active strip, you can right click on the color and use 'Copy to Selected':

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was great, it worked and saves a lot of time. :)