# Text Scrolling in a Window

Tags: transparency, text-object

I'm trying to put together a script to help create scrolling text. I'd like the text to scroll up within a container & be invisible before it enters and after it leaves the container. I've got a few working-ish versions of it. My application is very render time sensitive, though, and the versions I've created have very very very long render times for how simple this effect seems it would be.

An example image...

[image]

This image shows a cube's bounds surrounding a text object that has been converted to mesh. My understanding is that I cannot make the text transparent/clip it if the text is not mesh (is that true?).

Anyway, I'm achieving the effect, now, using a boolean modifier between the text mesh and cube. If the text moves to any side of the box, it gets clipped (which is exactly what I want).

[image]

However this process isn't perfect. I'm seeing some weird popping in and out of existence at the edges (on both the inside and outside of the cube). Note the "S" in "Something, and the "e" in "see", among others.

[image]

This popping is unpredictable for me; a letter may pop when partially bisected by the cube, but may or may not when bisect to a greater or lesser depth.

**Overall Question** -- How can I achieve this text effect? I'm trying more solutions which are increasingly ridiculous, but are achievable because I primarily script my Blender work, not do it by hand.

Comment: Hello :). Do you need the text to be 3D, or would a simple 2D mask in compositor be enough?

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ 2D would be enough.. will using the compositor bump the render time much? And would it require the text object to be on its own view layer?

Comment: I'm no expert, but there is a thread that could be useful https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32585/78972

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmgeK17vnrg

Comment: Shoot, well I do appreciate the link, but I've actually watched this video and his product by the end is not what he shows at the beginning. He never tells how he made the text become transparent before the end of the screen.